# pip install command creates syntax error : Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: installation, pip, syntax-error, traceback

I've been trying to install bs4 and selenium from the windows powershell, and here is the error message I get :

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\T470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 160, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\T470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\T470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 326, in run
    session = self.get_default_session(options)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\T470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 98, in get_default_session
    self._session = self.enter_context(self._build_session(options))
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\T470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 125, in _build_session
    session = PipSession(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\T470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\session.py", line 343, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\T470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\session.py", line 175, in user_agent
    setuptools_dist = get_default_environment().get_distribution("setuptools")
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\T470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\metadata\importlib\_envs.py", line 188, in get_distribution
    return next(matches, None)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\T470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\metadata\importlib\_envs.py", line 183, in <genexpr>
    matches = (
              ^
  File "C:\Users\T470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\metadata\base.py", line 612, in iter_all_distributions
    for dist in self._iter_distributions():
  File "C:\Users\T470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\metadata\importlib\_envs.py", line 176, in _iter_distributions
    for dist in finder.find_eggs(location):
  File "C:\Users\T470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\metadata\importlib\_envs.py", line 146, in find_eggs
    yield from self._find_eggs_in_zip(location)
  File "C:\Users\T470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\metadata\importlib\_envs.py", line 123, in _find_eggs_in_zip
    from pip._vendor.pkg_resources import find_eggs_in_zip
  File "C:\Users\T470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3251, in <module>
    @_call_aside
     ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\T470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3235, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\T470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3277, in _initialize_master_working_set
    tuple(
  File "C:\Users\T470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3278, in <genexpr>
    dist.activate(replace=False)
  File "C:\Users\T470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2785, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "C:\Users\T470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2284, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "C:\Users\T470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2217, in _handle_ns
    loader.load_module(packageName)
  File "C:\Users\T470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pygoogle\google.py", line 113
    print """PyGoogle %(__version__)s
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
```

I cannot install any pip package in my pc it returns that error
pip version is : pip 22.3.1
python version is : Python 3.11.1

Appreciate Your support .

I tried to install any pip package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've installed a package PyGoogle which is very old (2006) and works only with Python 2. You need to uninstall it:

```
pip uninstall -y pygoogle
```

If that doesn't work — remove the directory `C:\Users\T470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pygoogle`

Comment: Thank you so much, I couldn't use the pip uninstall, removed the directory, and it finally worked. Thank you again !